# Haunted by wererabbit's folksong

Tags: creature-design, gravity, moons

I've always been curious whenever I heard the mother wererabbit sings a popular folksong to the young, there is a  particular line in the lyric that seems to puzzle me. It goes likes this: "up up and away!... " I had a chance to talk to one of their elder regarding the origin of the song while my space shuttle docks at the lunar station for refueling, however I can't speak wererabbit and hence I got irritated and throw a volley of punches at the folk in the end my trip was cut short and I'm now studying the song behind bars.

**Question**

How can a wererabbit jumps high enough to escape the moon's gravity and then perform a re-entry into Earth's atmosphere unaided and probably unscathed? These wererabbits are known to possess incredible healing factor and can regenerate any form of laceration to the muscle tissues in mere seconds, however most of them are dimwitted.

**Note**

Comment below should there are doubts not pertaining to why they are called wererabbit and how they do their business(passing motion) in microgravity, I would appreciate the answer to elaborate on the art er... science behind the leap of faith I'm a great fan of numbers and equations. Please indulge me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get a wrabbit in space; all you will get is wererabbit dust.

I'll base my answer in this [what-if case](https://what-if.xkcd.com/28/)

In short, it states that dropping (no initial velocity) an steak from 250 km., the outer layer will become charred, with the center unaffected. The scenario is one of constant acceleartion while the atmosphera is non-existent/too thin, to deceleration (and a lot of heat) when the atmosphera becomes denser.

What changes in our scenario is that your rabbit must get all the energy for the journey at the moment of the jump. That means that all of that energy will be, at T+delta, *kinetic energy*. Without energy loses due to friction, at 100 km your bunny will have a potential energy of [61.6 MJ/kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy#ISS), which makes your minimum speed at launching at

1/2*v^2 = 61600000  --> v = 11.100 m/s, or almost 40.000 km/hour

To me, that is enough to say that you wererabbit will disintegrate<sup>1</sup>, no matter how fast he regenerates. Layer after layer of rabbit will be carbonized and taken away from the rabbit, exposing new layers.

If still not convinced, think that such a heating due to friction with the atmosphera will mean that the bunny will lose a significant part of the energy, so to reach the 100km mark it actually would need to jump even faster than the speed above mentioned.

<sup>1</sup>: Another option is that, at such speeds, the resistence of air is so big that your bunny gets squashed as if being dropped into hard concrete at terminal velocity.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions to your question.

1) Magic. Magic can generally explain everything.

2) Your were-rabbit actually is a spaceship. Seriously, if the were-rabbit gets its jumping energy from rocket fuel, and is covered in a layer of metal to resist frictional heating, and has a skeletal structure made of some kind of metal, and a parachute, it might survive that journey. However, by this point, it is more spaceship than rabbit.